# Add (change) event listener to a field at runtime

Tags: angular, datetime, input, event-binding

I have some field for a form, that are rendered using a `JSON` and an `*ngFor`.
The number and order of the fields can vary, as well as the type. They could be either `datetime` fields or text field, based on parameters that came on the `JSON`.

The only constant is that the first two are always datetime fields, `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

Now I would like to be able to detect when the values of these fields change, so I can do some checking if the `StartDate` is lower or equal than the `EndDate`.

Here is my template:

```
// Code to render the fields, be it datetime or text
  <div class="form-group">
  <div *ngIf="IsDateTime(campo.data_type); else textField">
       <app-datetimepicker #campoData [Cabecalho]="campo.alias" ></app-datetimepicker>
  </div>
    <ng-template #textField>
     <label>{{campo.alias}}</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </ng-template>
```

Since the fields don't *exist* at compile time only after the request for the `JSON` finishes, I cannot add `(change)` to the HTML, also because there might be other datetime inputs but I only want the first two.

I can get the two fields and their values, I am searching for a way to add a listener for when the input values changes, but so far had no success.

I've tried `Renderer2` but got and error message, and most of the questions I find tell me  to add the `(change)` event to the template, but that doesn't fit what I am needing.

How could I go around doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

1. Declare this new observable:

```
formValueChanges$: Observable<any>;
```

2. once you have your form initialized, subscribe to its changes:

```
// yourForm should be the name of your form
this.formValueChanges$ = this.yourForm.valueChanges
   .pipe(
      //takeUntil(this.destroy$),
      debounceTime(0),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
```

3. Once you have that subscribtion, you can filter by the field you wanted (*campo* in your example, I guess):

```
this.formValueChanges$  
   .pipe(   
      //takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        distinctUntilKeyChanged('campo')
      )
      .subscribe(formValue => {

         // Here should be your logic
      });
```

*NOTE: You have to do the appropriate imports*

```
import {
  map,
  takeUntil,
  filter,
  debounceTime,
  distinctUntilChanged,
  shareReplay,
  distinctUntilKeyChanged,
  finalize,
} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```